# Обфускация LuaU скриптов на C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, обфускация

Хочу написать обфускатор **LuaU** скриптов на **C++**, какие алгоритмы шифрования строк самые безопасные и эффективные? Что значит *"Защита констант"*, я так понимаю к обычным `constant string` это не относится? Как работает *"Анти дамп"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Хочу написать обфускатор LuaU скриптов на C++

Зачем? Оно тебе надо?! Насколько я помню LuaU в первую очередь позиционируется на наилучший performance. (Хотя я такого по сравнению с обычным Lua 5.4 не особо замечал)

> какие алгоритмы шифрования строк самые безопасные и эффективные?

Почти полный комплект в последних OpenSSL

> Что значит "Защита констант"

Полное их отсутствие. Полное избегание статических адресов и кода из которых можно что-то вынуть или повлиять на работу кода. Включая загрузку приложения через VirtualAlloc и создание Executible памяти на лету.

> Как работает "Анти дамп"?

По факту не грузить приложение целиком а кусочками. Например тебе нужно какую-то функцию выполнить, ты её расшифровываешь из секрета, и загружаешь в память. После отработки выгружаешь. Это позволяет эффективно бороться с разного рода отладчиками. И уж темболее не позволит выгрузить дамп памяти на диск, для дальнейшего изучения.

Comment: А есть какая то разница между обфускаторами на луа, на плюсах или на пайтоне? на плюсах больше контроля над кодом или?

Comment: @esohasl Как день и ночь, код который работает в VM уже по своей сути небезопасен. Ему можно скормить например перепечённую VM для запуска. Код написанный на плюсах по своей сути таких недостатков лишен. Но нечего не мешает например запустить твою программу в VM вместе с OS. Не существует готового решения для этого вопроса. Вопрос состоит более в том насколько паранойно строится защита. Apple в погоне за паранойей создали целый сопроцессор (назвали его Secure Enclave) думали решить все проблемы одним разом. Хацкеры ответили на это "Железными" патчами. И айфоны продолжили ломаться.

Comment: А если это не приложение какое нибудь, а обычный скрипт к игре, который будет инжектится в игру?

Comment: Ну как сказать.. Некоторые игровые движки поддерживают тот-же LuaJIT или Luac версии скриптов.. Но обсуфикацией или уж тем более шифрованием это даже не пахнет. Это всего лишь перекомпилированные версии того-же dot.lua файла, где текстовое представление заменено на токены. Как пример `print("hello")`  это тоже самое что  `[токен_call][адрес_print][токен_текст:5][Hello]` как понимаешь это распаковывается на раз-два даже без особых хакерских знаний. Глянь статью о токенах в PHP https://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php конечно они в Lua другие но понимание придёт.

Comment: к примеру вот такие скрипты: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/itsnoctural/Destiny/main/scripts/2%20Player%20Computer%20Tycoon/main.lua

или 

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/itsnoctural/Destiny/main/scripts/My%20Prison/main.lua

вот этим вдохновляюсь, еще я смотрел исходники луау обфускатора ironbrew2 на шарпе, выглядит все это очень сложно, точно больше чем 1000 строк, но я и на меньше и легче не ожидал, просто вся эта тема не популярная мягко говоря, и никаких роликов и туториалов как начинать что нибудь писать нету даже на английском, может я плохо искал

Comment: этот айронбрев, все говорят что его очень легко деобфусцировать, поэтому 1000+ строк думаю это еще мало, хотя возможно я не прав и судить по строкам не правильно, https://controlc.com/1cac198a вот обфусцированный код с айронбрев, выглядит и в правду не совсем надежно, эти переменные с стринг байт чар и прочее выглядит не совсем безопасно, а вот мунсек в3 выглядит очень даже неплохо так, никаких переменных а просто рандомный текст из ниоткуда который еще и работает полностью корректно